# How can I make this layout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a kind of animation in a layout, but I have no idea how to do it. Imagine a list with 7 (just for example) elements. However, the sixth and seventh elements are initially positioned below the fifth. When this list is scrolled, the fifth element moves out of the way, revealing the sixth, and so on. In this link, there is a Figma layout that illustrates what I am trying to achieve:  https://www.figma.com/file/RBJUpcskBS3uImeyHDkstW/Untitled?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=YwR33X6YBswv1o8a-1.

If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I don't have any code to show because everything I've tried doesn't make sense, haha."

Comment: [Please take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So, just a horizontal roll with a scroll (ListView)?  Or does it need to snap to discrete one-block horizontal slides (PageView)?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do what I wanted, I used the StackedCardCarousel library as a base, in the code so far I need to import the library, I believe there is still room to improve the code but for now (the code contains writing in Brazilian Portuguese)

```
    `class HorizontalStackedCardCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
    HorizontalStackedCardCarousel({
    required List<Widget> items,
    StackedCardCarouselType type = StackedCardCarouselType.cardsStack,
    double initialOffset = 00.0,
    required spaceBetweenItems,
    bool applyTextScaleFactor = true,
    PageController? pageController,
    OnPageChanged? onPageChanged,
  })  : assert(items.isNotEmpty),
        _items = items,
        _type = type,
        _initialOffset = initialOffset,
        _spaceBetweenItems = spaceBetweenItems,
        _applyTextScaleFactor = applyTextScaleFactor,
        _pageController = pageController ?? PageController(),
        _onPageChanged = onPageChanged;

  final List<Widget> _items;
  final StackedCardCarouselType _type;
  final double _initialOffset;
  final double _spaceBetweenItems;
  final bool _applyTextScaleFactor;
  final PageController _pageController;
  final OnPageChanged? _onPageChanged;

  @override
  HorizontalStackedCardCarouselState createState() =>
      HorizontalStackedCardCarouselState();
}

class HorizontalStackedCardCarouselState
    extends State<HorizontalStackedCardCarousel> {
  double _pageValue = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Adicione o deslocamento inicial desejado
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _pageValue = 4.0; // ou o valor desejado
      widget._pageController.jumpToPage(_pageValue.toInt());
    });

    widget._pageController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _pageValue = widget._pageController.page!;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void onPageChanged(int index) {
    // Prevent the user from scrolling to pages with index less than 3
    if (index < 4) {
      widget._pageController.jumpToPage(4);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClickThroughStack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _stackedCards(context),
        PageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: widget._pageController,
          itemCount: widget._items.length,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _stackedCards(BuildContext context) {
    double textScaleFactor = 1.0;
    if (widget._applyTextScaleFactor) {
      final double mediaQueryFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
      if (mediaQueryFactor > 1.0) {
        textScaleFactor = mediaQueryFactor;
      }
    }

    final List<Widget> _positionedCards =
        widget._items.asMap().entries.map((MapEntry<int, Widget> item) {
      double position = widget._initialOffset;

      if (_pageValue > item.key) {
        position += (_pageValue - item.key) *
            widget._spaceBetweenItems *
            textScaleFactor;
      }
      switch (widget._type) {
        case StackedCardCarouselType.fadeOutStack:
          double opacity = 1.0;
          double scale = 1.0;
          if (_pageValue - item.key < 0) {
            final double factor = 1 + (_pageValue - item.key);
            opacity = factor < 0.0 ? 0.0 : pow(factor, 1.5).toDouble();
            scale = factor < 0.0 ? 0.0 : pow(factor, 0.1).toDouble();
          }
          return Positioned(
            right: position,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: scale,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: opacity,
                child: item.value,
              ),
            ),
          );
        case StackedCardCarouselType.cardsStack:
        default:
          double scale = 1.0;
          if (_pageValue - item.key < 0) {
            final double factor = 1 + (_pageValue - item.key);
            scale = 0.95 + (factor * 0.1 / 2);
          }
          return Positioned(
            right: position,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: scale,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  item.value, // O container da imagem
                  if (item.key >= 4 && item.key != widget._items.length - 1) // Exibir o container apartir do index 4 ate o penultimo index
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: _isContainerVisible(item.key) ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), // Ajuste conforme necessário
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black38,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              '${widget._items.length - item.key - 1}+', // Exibir o índice ajustado
                              style: GoogleFonts.acme(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
      }
    }).toList();

    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: _positionedCards.reversed.toList(),
    );
  }

  bool _isContainerVisible(int index) {
    // Ajuste conforme necessário, dependendo da lógica exata para determinar a visibilidade
    return index >= 4 && _pageValue <= index;
  }
}
```

`

to use it I need an auxiliary class because the view was recreating itself, this is the auxiliary class:
`

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double itemWidth;
  final double screenHeight;

  const MyWidget({required this.itemWidth, required this.screenHeight});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late HorizontalStackedCardCarousel _carousel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _carousel = HorizontalStackedCardCarousel(
      spaceBetweenItems: widget.itemWidth + 5,
      items: List.generate(
        10,
        (index) => Container(
          width: widget.itemWidth,
          // Desired width for each container
          height: widget.screenHeight,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://thypix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Sommerlandschaft-Bilder-30.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _carousel,
    );
  }
}
```

`

I call this class within my main view and this way I can show the image carousel in miniature, horizontally as shown in the image: [demonstrative image of image carousel[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEg7c.jpg)

Comment: Please write your entire answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English-only site](/help/non-english-questions).